# Trying to get a For Loop to work

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, for-loop

I'm trying to write a program where on the first line, you enter the number of times you want a for loop to iterate, on the second line, you enter the value of the array, and on the third line, you enter the numbers that you want in the array. My program either does not do what I want it to do, or it crashes on me. This is the code that I have for the program so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    int n = input.nextInt();


    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int value = input.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[value];
        arr[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

What can I do? Please help. I've tried everything! Also, it would help if someone could help me with sorting the numbers in ascending order, followed by displaying the middle number in each line, but first thing's first. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is more of what you are after.  I output the entries individually but you could combine that easily enough.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
       Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
       try
       {
       System.out.println("Number of times to loop:");

       int numEntries = input.nextInt();
       int[][] valueArrays = new int[numEntries][];

        for (int i=0; i<numEntries; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Size of array #"+i+": ");
            int arrayLen = input.nextInt();
            int[] inputArray = new int[arrayLen];
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayLen; j++)
            {
              System.out.println("Enter value at index "+j+": ");
              inputArray[j] = input.nextInt();
            }

            Arrays.sort(inputArray);
            valueArrays[i] = inputArray;
        }

        for (int l=0; l < valueArrays.length; l++)
        {
            int[] values = valueArrays[l];
            for (int m=0; m < values.length; m++)
            {
                System.out.println("Value of array #"+l+" saved at index "+m +": " + values[m]);
            }

            if ((values.length % 2) == 0)
            {
                int start = values.length/2;
                int end = start + 1;
                System.out.println("Middle values in array #"+l+" saved at indices " + start + " and " + end);                                          
            }
            else
            {
                int start = values.length/2;
                System.out.println("Middle value in array #"+l+" saved at index " + start);                                         
            }

        }

    }
    finally
    {
        input.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: That's good, but I'm stuck on the second loop. I'm only supposed to display the middle number and the loop is displaying the whole array. Any help you can give on that?

Comment: Glad to help. I guess you figured out the "m" loop was printing out the array in sorted order so if you didn't need that just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new array on each iteration inside the loop.

You should get `int[] arr = new int[value];` out of the loop:

```
int arraySize = input.nextInt();
int[] arr = new int[arraySize];

for (int i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
{
    int value = input.nextInt();
    arr[i] = value;
}
```

If you don't want to limit the user for a size, use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I tried to loop it 4 times and it only did it once.

Comment: You need to input something.. `nextInt` waits for your input.

Comment: `run:
4
5
1 6 4 8 3
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)`
This is what it looks like when I tried to run it.

Comment: The `4` is how many times I wanted it to loop, the `5` is the size of the array, and the numbers after that are the ones I try to put in the array.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem 1:My program either does not do what I want it to do.

Dont initialize array inside for loop as loop wiil create a new array every time you iterate it.

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter no. of elements in array");
    int n = input.nextInt();

    int[] arr = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Array length set to "+n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter value for index "+i);

        arr[i] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(arr[i]+" Value saved at index "+i);
    }
```

#### DEMO1

> Problem 2(described in comments below):Sorting arrays and displaying the middle number

```
class Ideone
{
    static int[] countingSort(int[] numbers) {
    int max = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > max)
            max = numbers[i];
    }

    int[] sortedNumbers = new int[max+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        sortedNumbers[numbers[i]]++;
    }

    int insertPosition = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sortedNumbers[i]; j++) {
                    numbers[insertPosition] = i;
                    insertPosition++;
            }
    }
    return numbers;
}



    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Number of times to loop:");
    int n = input.nextInt();

   // int[] arr = new int[n];
   // System.out.println("Array length set to "+n);
    for (int i=1; i<=3; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Size of array #"+i+": ");
        int alen = input.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[alen];
        System.out.println("Value in array #"+i+": ");
        for (int j=0; j<alen; j++){
        System.out.println("Enter value at index "+j+": ");
         arr[j] = input.nextInt();
        }
        arr=Ideone.countingSort(arr);
        for (int l=0; l<alen; l++)
         System.out.println(arr[l]+" Value of array #"+i+" saved at index "+l);
       System.out.println("Middle value in array #"+i+" saved at index "+arr[alen/2]);
        }

    }

}
```

#### DEMO2

Comment: I'm sorry, for this does not work. I told the program to loop 3 times, it only looped once.

Comment: @Frank have you checked the demo above given in my answer

Comment: Yes. I put the code into my program and tested it. It did not work.

Comment: This is what the output is supposed to look like:
 `Number of times to loop: 3 /
Size of array #1: 5 /
Values in array #1: 1 2 3 4 5 /
Size of array #2: 3 /
Values in array #2: 9 4 2 /
Size of array #3: 7 /
Values in array #3: 8 10 2 11 20 1 15`
Between each slash is a nextLine.
Make sense? Then, I'm supposed to take each array, sort it in numerical order, find the middle number (notice these are all odd numbered values), then display the middle number.